# Common SCSS standards

Tags: sass, standards

Are there any coding/styling standards for my .scss files?
I have seen selectors span a whole page and very small snippets nested very deeply.
Are there any baseline standards to go off of?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: I cannot find anything on any sort of standards, so it would be good to hear about opinions and where they might have generated from.

Comment: As @basementkeyboardhero mentions, this will be mostly opinion, but I tend to really like the following guidelines: http://cssguidelin.es - Its not specific to SASS, but with SASS its best not to nest too deeply as it makes it hard later. But have a read there, it helped me think about my structure.

Comment: Thanks @somethinghere, sorry for the vague question. I will look into established CSS guidelines.

Comment: [http://sass-guidelin.es/](http://sass-guidelin.es/) is very informative. It's more an extension of [http://cssguidelin.es/](http://cssguidelin.es/) based around Scss markup.